# Vaadin 14 - grid disappearing when using nested layout

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid

After implementing nested layouts i faced the problem with rendering component containing grid. The analysis shows that  is present in html but it has display-block attributes and the grid is never visible.

I read the similar question ([Vaadin 14 - Grid not Displaying/Populating When Used in Nested Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57797262/vaadin-14-grid-not-displaying-populating-when-used-in-nested-layout)) but the suggestions listed there brought me no result.

Here comes my code:

MainLayout.kt:

```
@Theme(value = Material::class, variant = Material.DARK)
class MainLayout : Composite<Div>(), RouterLayout {

    //Component to delegate content through.
    private val mainContent: Div = Div()
    private val layout = VerticalLayout(
            Span("from MainLayout top"),
            mainContent,
            Span("from MainLayout bottom"))


    override fun showRouterLayoutContent(hasElement: HasElement) {

        Objects.requireNonNull(hasElement)
        Objects.requireNonNull(hasElement.element)
        mainContent.removeAll()
        mainContent.element.appendChild(hasElement.element)
    }

    init {
        content.add(layout)
    }
}
```

LayoutWithMenuBar.kt:

```
@ParentLayout(value = MainLayout::class)
class LayoutWithMenuBar : Composite<Div>(), RouterLayout {

    private val mainContent: Div = Div()

    private val menuBar = HorizontalLayout(
            RouterLink("Home", MainView::class.java),
            RouterLink("Tprojects", TProjectDashboard::class.java),
            RouterLink("ViewA", ViewA::class.java),
            RouterLink("ViewB", ViewB::class.java))


    private val root = VerticalLayout(menuBar, mainContent)

    override fun showRouterLayoutContent(hasElement: HasElement) {

        Objects.requireNonNull(hasElement)
        Objects.requireNonNull(hasElement.element)
        mainContent.removeAll()
        mainContent.element.appendChild(hasElement.element)
    }


    init {

        content.add(root)
    }
}
```

and a component containing grid - TProjectDashboard:

```
@Route("dashboard/tproject", layout = LayoutWithMenuBar::class)
class TProjectDashboard(@Autowired val tprojectService: TProjectService): VerticalLayout() {

    var tprojectGrid = Grid<TProject>(TProject::class.java)

    init {
        //tprojectGrid
        tprojectGrid.setColumns(
                TProject::tprojectUuid.name,
                TProject::tprojectClass.name,
                TProject::tprojectState.name,
                TProject::tentityState.name,
                TProject::size.name)

        tprojectGrid.setItems(tprojectService.findAll())

        tprojectGrid.setSizeFull()
        tprojectGrid.setWidthFull()
        tprojectGrid.setHeightFull()

        add(tprojectGrid)

        setSizeFull()
        setHeightFull()
        setWidthFull()
    }
}
```

The same result i have when changing TProjectDashboard parent from VerticalLayout to Composite.
The nested layouts approach works well for simple components like Span and if i remove layout reference from @Route annotation i will see my grid.

Here is the screen how it looks like now:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/139CL.png)

Would appreciate for any hints or solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably a sizing issue that unfortunately happens too often. I would start with calling `setSizeFull()` on the `mainContent` div. If that doesn't help, go through the elements in the browser devtools and try to see where the size disappears, e.g. what is the first element that has 0 width or height.

**Edit:** Setting `setSizeFull()` on all components works. I would simplify your layouts slightly, though, by changing the composites to be of type `VerticalLayout`. Then you can get rid of a lot of the `setSizeFull()` calls.

The code below is in Java as I don't have Kotlin set up, you can call `getContent().setSizeFull()` in `MainLayout` if you want it to take the full height of the page.

`MainLayout`

```
@Theme(value = Material.class, variant = Material.DARK)
public class MainLayout extends Composite<VerticalLayout> implements RouterLayout {

    //Component to delegate content through.
    private Div mainContent = new Div();

    public MainLayout() {
        getContent().add(
                new Span("from MainLayout top"),
                mainContent,
                new Span("from MainLayout bottom"));
        mainContent.setSizeFull();
    }

    @Override
    public void showRouterLayoutContent(HasElement hasElement) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(hasElement);
        Objects.requireNonNull(hasElement.getElement());
        mainContent.removeAll();
        mainContent.getElement().appendChild(hasElement.getElement());
    }
}
```

`LayoutWithMenuBar`

```
@ParentLayout(value = MainLayout.class)
public class LayoutWithMenuBar extends Composite<VerticalLayout> implements RouterLayout {

    private Div mainContent = new Div();

    private HorizontalLayout menuBar = new HorizontalLayout(
            new RouterLink("Tprojects", TProjectDashboard.class));

    public LayoutWithMenuBar() {
        getContent().add(menuBar, mainContent);
        mainContent.setSizeFull();
    }

    @Override
    public void showRouterLayoutContent(HasElement hasElement) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(hasElement);
        Objects.requireNonNull(hasElement.getElement());
        mainContent.removeAll();
        mainContent.getElement().appendChild(hasElement.getElement());
    }
}
```

`TProjectDashboard`

```
@Route(value = "dashboard/tproject", layout = LayoutWithMenuBar.class)
public class TProjectDashboard extends VerticalLayout {

    private Grid<TProject> tprojectGrid = new Grid<>(TProject.class);

    public TProjectDashboard() {

        tprojectGrid.setItems(
                new TProject("Erik", "Software Engineer"),
                new TProject("Fia", "Kindergarden teacher"),
                new TProject("Jack", "All trades")
        );

        add(tprojectGrid);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. I tried what u said - added setSizeFull to all content entities from MainLayout down to my problem component,ran project clean and then rebuild it, but it didnt help.
As for zero size, i looked it again into Mozilla, the only way i found to unhide the grid was changing elements style with removing "display:block". I completely do not understand what makes the engine to render the grid that way. I saw smth a bit related to the subject in one forum where was suggested that the problem is with scroller and its height, but i havent found the soluton yet.

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Thank you very much, you were completely right, sorry for wasting your time. I changed Composite<Div>  to Composite<VerticalLayout> and also reimported my project into Idea and rebuilded it after and it started to work. 
Not sure exactly what my fault was - insufficient rebuild procedure or using Div in 
Composite.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: It wasn't a waste of time, now it's documented here! And it required setting size full on the content, mainLayout, and vertical layouts, so it was quite complex.